# Use dash in printf

Tags: bash, printf

How can I use a dash in `printf` string?

```
x=xxx
printf -v args "-x=%s" "$x"
printf "$var"
```

But it gives an error:

```
./tmp.sh: line 2: printf: -x: invalid option
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
```

I know that it's because `printf` interprets `-x` as an option, but how to overcome it?

I use `printf` to create a string that will correspond to command line arguments like `-x=xxx -y=yyy -z=zzz`. Then I want to call a tool like

`eval $tool args`

Comment: You don't want to use `printf` at all, as you should be building an array of arguments to pass to `tool`: `foo=(-x xxx -y yyy); tool "${foo[@]}"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`printf` supports the conventional end-of-options argument `--`:

```
$ printf -- '-x\n'
-x
```

Comment: POSIX requires printf to deal with `--`.

Comment: Such support is usually indicated by requiring conformance to the Utility Syntax Guidelines, but `printf` makes no mention of such a requirement. (At least that I could find; I often fail to find things in the place where I expect them.)

Comment: POSIX gives no permission to disregard the USG for printf.

Comment: dash is not POSIX compliant in many cases. It would e.g. need to support multi byte characters in case it is not run only on a tiny embedded system.

Comment: @chepner, see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_04. _Standard utilities that do not accept options, but that do accept operands, shall recognize "--" as a first argument to be discarded_.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks, that's the section I missed.

Comment: `printf -- -x` works for me with dash 0.5.8-2.10

Comment: On ASCII based systems, you can also use `printf '\55x'`

Comment: Ugh, I only tested `printf --`, which gives the same error as `printf` alone.

Comment: @schily: The OP was using "dash" to mean "ASCII hyphen/minus sign" (not one of the various Unicode dashes). No need to handle multibyte characters unless you're on a really weird (non-ASCII) system.

Comment: Your statement is completely unrelated. dash is non-POSIX. If you don't believe this, set IFS to ö while you are in a multi byte locale.

Comment: Let's drop further discussion of `dash` as off-topic. I only brought it up as a test to see if `printf` was required to support `--`; as `dash` tends to be far more POSIX-compliant than most shells, I took the failure of a bad test (`printf --`) as evidence (not proof, mind you) that support for `--` was optional. The overall level of POSIX compliance in `dash` isn't really relevant.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the end of options (`--`) argument to have `printf` treat the dash literally:

```
printf -v var -- '-x=%s' "$x"
```

Output:

```
$ x=xxx && printf -v var -- '-x=%s' "$x" && echo $var
-x=xxx
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your `printf` seems to take options, use a format string to output both the `-x` and the value of the variable:

```
printf '%s=%s' '-x' "$x"
```

To call a tool with a pre-generated command line, don't put the command line arguments into a string.  Use `set` to set the values of `$@` instead:

```
set -- -x="$x" -y="$y" -z="$z"
```

Then call the tool:

```
tool "$@"
```

This will ensure that the tool gets the correct number of arguments, properly quoted, even if one or several of the values, `$x`, `$y`, or `$z`, contains spaces.

Or, using a `bash` array:

```
args=( -x="$x" -y="$y" -z="$z" )

tool "${args[@]}"
```